# nvd3 multibarchart height and label issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using the reusable NVD3 multibarchart, I have 4 serious and 250+ categories. this chart is working but the rectangles are very small and some of the labels are overlapping.

the out see below.

[nvd3 multibarchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTDZD.png)

the code which i am using is

```
var data =  [{"key":"Ready","total":135,"values":[{"label":"111","value":1},{"label":"136","value":1},{"label":"155","value":2},{"label":"525","value":2},{"label":"RD ","value":7},    {"label":"601","value":3},{"label":"624","value":2},{"label":"155","value":1},{"label":"ADC","value":2},{"label":"177","value":2},{"label":"152","value":2},{"label":"026","value":3},    {"label":"623","value":2},{"label":"800","value":1},{"label":"067","value":2},{"label":"096","value":2},{"label":"133","value":1},{"label":"Mer","value":1},{"label":"Mer","value":2},{"label":"050","value":1},{"label":"138","value":1},{"label":"098","value":4},{"label":"080","value":2},{"label":"010","value":1},{"label":"034","value":1},{"label":"069","value":1},{"label":"020","value":1},{"label":"060","value":1},{"label":"037","value":1},{"label":"006","value":3},{"label":"167","value":2},{"label":"117","value":1},{"label":"143","value":1},{"label":"IDP","value":1},{"label":"185","value":1},{"label":"575","value":2},{"label":"146","value":2},{"label":"173","value":1},{"label":"171","value":3},{"label":"633","value":1},{"label":"010","value":4},{"label":"040","value":2},{"label":"068","value":2},{"label":"175","value":2},{"label":"054","value":3},{"label":"096","value":1},{"label":"096","value":5},{"label":"154","value":2},{"label":"050","value":7},{"label":"096","value":4},{"label":"096","value":2},{"label":"034","value":3},{"label":"069","value":2},{"label":"020","value":2},{"label":"060","value":3},{"label":"118","value":1},{"label":"164","value":3},{"label":"415","value":3},{"label":"138","value":3},{"label":"126","value":1},{"label":"037","value":2},{"label":"065","value":3},{"label":"157","value":2},{"label":"SCC","value":2}]},{"key":"Not Started","total":19890,"values":[{"label":"111","value":22},{"label":"136","value":216},{"label":"155","value":300},{"label":"525","value":174},{"label":"RD ","value":1253},{"label":"601","value":797},{"label":"624","value":271},{"label":"155","value":60},{"label":"ADC","value":272},{"label":"177","value":159},{"label":"152","value":426},{"label":"026","value":519},{"label":"623","value":562},{"label":"800","value":69},{"label":"067","value":643},{"label":"096","value":135},{"label":"133","value":272},{"label":"Mer","value":97},{"label":"Mer","value":303},{"label":"050","value":119},{"label":"138","value":54},{"label":"098","value":644},{"label":"080","value":384},{"label":"010","value":121},{"label":"034","value":21},{"label":"069","value":99},{"label":"020","value":42},{"label":"060","value":31},{"label":"037","value":54},{"label":"006","value":337},{"label":"167","value":303},{"label":"117","value":221},{"label":"143","value":88},{"label":"IDP","value":282},{"label":"185","value":102},{"label":"575","value":313},{"label":"146","value":139},{"label":"173","value":93},{"label":"171","value":210},{"label":"633","value":103},{"label":"010","value":733},{"label":"040","value":356},{"label":"068","value":475},{"label":"175","value":301},{"label":"054","value":466},{"label":"096","value":42},{"label":"096","value":739},{"label":"154","value":295},{"label":"050","value":679},{"label":"096","value":423},{"label":"096","value":165},{"label":"034","value":380},{"label":"069","value":350},{"label":"020","value":560},{"label":"060","value":665},{"label":"118","value":112},{"label":"164","value":762},{"label":"415","value":174},{"label":"138","value":346},{"label":"126","value":101},{"label":"037","value":346},{"label":"065","value":563},{"label":"157","value":416},{"label":"SCC","value":131}]},{"key":"Obsolet","total":861,"values":[{"label":"111","value":1},{"label":"136","value":16},{"label":"155","value":16},{"label":"525","value":3},{"label":"RD ","value":32},{"label":"601","value":23},{"label":"624","value":17},{"label":"155","value":1},{"label":"ADC","value":10},{"label":"177","value":5},{"label":"152","value":23},{"label":"026","value":25},{"label":"623","value":25},{"label":"800","value":1},{"label":"067","value":31},{"label":"096","value":3},{"label":"133","value":14},{"label":"Mer","value":1},{"label":"Mer","value":9},{"label":"050","value":2},{"label":"138","value":2},{"label":"098","value":15},{"label":"080","value":9},{"label":"010","value":7},{"label":"069","value":7},{"label":"020","value":5},{"label":"006","value":16},{"label":"167","value":23},{"label":"117","value":8},{"label":"143","value":5},{"label":"IDP","value":20},{"label":"185","value":10},{"label":"575","value":22},{"label":"146","value":12},{"label":"173","value":2},{"label":"171","value":12},{"label":"633","value":7},{"label":"010","value":27},{"label":"040","value":21},{"label":"068","value":23},{"label":"175","value":19},{"label":"054","value":19},{"label":"096","value":1},{"label":"096","value":26},{"label":"154","value":18},{"label":"050","value":31},{"label":"096","value":19},{"label":"096","value":10},{"label":"034","value":21},{"label":"069","value":21},{"label":"020","value":26},{"label":"060","value":22},{"label":"118","value":7},{"label":"164","value":19},{"label":"415","value":8},{"label":"138","value":17},{"label":"126","value":6},{"label":"037","value":15},{"label":"065","value":22},{"label":"157","value":17},{"label":"SCC","value":6}]},{"key":"Started","total":379,"values":[{"label":"111","value":2},{"label":"136","value":8},{"label":"155","value":5},{"label":"525","value":6},{"label":"RD ","value":9},{"label":"601","value":5},{"label":"624","value":5},{"label":"155","value":4},{"label":"ADC","value":5},{"label":"177","value":5},{"label":"152","value":6},{"label":"026","value":6},{"label":"623","value":8},{"label":"800","value":5},{"label":"067","value":10},{"label":"096","value":7},{"label":"133","value":5},{"label":"Mer","value":4},{"label":"Mer","value":9},{"label":"050","value":1},{"label":"138","value":1},{"label":"098","value":11},{"label":"080","value":5},{"label":"010","value":1},{"label":"069","value":3},{"label":"060","value":1},{"label":"006","value":10},{"label":"167","value":5},{"label":"117","value":7},{"label":"143","value":4},{"label":"IDP","value":5},{"label":"185","value":4},{"label":"575","value":7},{"label":"146","value":4},{"label":"173","value":5},{"label":"171","value":5},{"label":"633","value":4},{"label":"010","value":7},{"label":"040","value":7},{"label":"068","value":7},{"label":"175","value":5},{"label":"054","value":10},{"label":"096","value":5},{"label":"096","value":15},{"label":"154","value":6},{"label":"050","value":10},{"label":"096","value":11},{"label":"096","value":11},{"label":"034","value":8},{"label":"069","value":7},{"label":"020","value":9},{"label":"060","value":8},{"label":"118","value":4},{"label":"164","value":8},{"label":"415","value":7},{"label":"138","value":6},{"label":"126","value":4},{"label":"037","value":5},{"label":"065","value":8},{"label":"157","value":7},{"label":"SCC","value":7}]}];





(function(data) {
 nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.label })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value })
    .forceY([0])// To make 10 to be starting point.
    //.margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
    .showValues(true)
    .height(2500)
    .showControls(true);        
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(','));
d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart)
    .attr('height', 5500);
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

return chart;

});})(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlap is because:
In a key example **Ready**:

Has **value 2** for **label 155**

```
{
    "label": "155",
    "value": 2
}
```

later it has **value 1** for **value 155**

```
, {
    "label": "155",
    "value": 1
  }
```

this is the reason for overlap (it is trying to show 2 and 1 on label 155).

**Fix:**

1. Ensure that for a label there is only **one value** for a given key.
2. Increase the size of the svg like [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DmBYjhl2K8IUe9pPXqGc?p=preview)

Comment: Dear Cyril, Thanks for the quick findings, i have corrected my data and now no overlapping.

Comment: but still i am not able to increase the bar's rect height. and also the stocked and groupped options not working. pls check the same http://plnkr.co/edit/V4CTzSNIHkfftCxeZcXs?p=preview..

Comment: you cannot make a stacked chart when your 1st key has some 10 data..2nd key has some 20 data values and so on... They all need to have same number of data. See here http://plnkr.co/edit/vdYlaPCyc0S0v9VsUGjB?p=preview